# Windows batch file: set string+number variables to contents of cmd-line parameters?

Tags: windows, batch-file, for-loop, cmd

I am trying to write a batch file that will set variables named VPARM1, VPARM2, etc. to the contents of the command line variables, %1, %2, etc. There is one twist to this: if the content of %1, %2, etc is the name of an existing file, I want to parse it into path and filename and clear the original variable.

In another thread, Matt Williamson showed me how to parse the name of the existing file into its parts, like this (his code):

```
@echo off 
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

FOR %%a IN (%*) DO (
if exist %%a set VDOSPATH="%%~dpa"
if exist %%a set VDOSFILE="%%~nxa"
echo(!VDOSPATH! !VDOSFILE!
)
```

What I now want to do is this: if %1, %2, etc. is NOT an existing filename, I want to set the variable VPARM# to the content of %#, so that if %3 is "hello" I want to end with VPARM3="hello", but if %2 is the name of existing file I do not want VPARM2 to exist.

I've tried many varieties of FOR /L and quotation marks to process %1, %2, etc., but nothing works at all. I'll be very grateful for any help with this. Again, the answer is probably obvious to experts but not to me.

P.S. The reason I need to set the VPARM variables is that my batch file opens a program that can read those variables from the environment. But the other program doesn't take parameters itself, and doesn't know what do with %1, %2, etc., as set in the batch file. (I hope that's clear.)

EDIT: Thanks to Magoo's answer below, I was able to write this batch file that (1) parses a command-line parameter into a path and filename (VDOSPATH and VDOSFILE), if the parameter exists as a file and (2) sets the other command-line parameters as new, named parameters (VPARM1, VPARM2, etc.):

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set /a fcount=0
FOR %%a IN (%*) DO (
set /a fcount+=1
if exist %%a (
set VDOSPATH="%%~dpa"
set VDOSFILE="%%~nxa"
) else (
set VPARM!fcount!=%%a
)
)
```

Thank you again!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```dos
@echo off 
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

:: remove variables starting fexists
FOR  /F "delims==" %%a In ('set fexists 2^>Nul') DO SET "%%a="

SET /a fcount=0

FOR %%a IN (%*) DO (
 SET /a fcount+=1
 if exist %%a (
  SET "fexists!fcount!=%%a"
  set VDOSPATH="%%~dpa"
  set VDOSFILE="%%~nxa"
  echo(!VDOSPATH! !VDOSFILE!
 )
)

SET fexists

GOTO :EOF
```

If you want the numbers to be sequential rather than positional, move the `set /a fcount+=1` into the `if exist` block (ie. down 1 line)

---

Addition, given response:

```dos
@echo off 
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

:: remove variables starting fexists, notfexists
For %%b IN (fexists notfexists) DO FOR  /F "delims==" %%a In ('set %%b 2^>Nul') DO SET "%%a="

SET /a fcount=0
SET "flist="
SET "notflist="

FOR %%a IN (%*) DO (
 SET /a fcount+=1
 if exist %%a (
  SET "flist=!flist! %%a"
  SET "fexists!fcount!=%%a"
  set VDOSPATH="%%~dpa"
  set VDOSFILE="%%~nxa"
  echo(!VDOSPATH! !VDOSFILE!
 ) ELSE (
  SET "notflist=!notflist! %%a"
  SET "notfexists!fcount!=%%a"
 )
)

SET fexists
SET notfexists
SET flist
SET notflist

GOTO :EOF
```

On my system given that `q22682214.bat` is the name of the batch file and the current directory is `c:\106x`, executing

```
q22862214c xwsl.bat notme hello4 xx.csv what "\program files (x86)\desktop.ini" \pagefile.sys
```

Yields

```
"c:\106x\" "xwsl.bat"
"c:\106x\" "xx.csv"
"c:\Program Files (x86)\" "desktop.ini"
"c:\" "pagefile.sys"

fexists1=xwsl.bat
fexists4=xx.csv
fexists6="\program files (x86)\desktop.ini"
fexists7=\pagefile.sys

notfexists2=notme
notfexists3=hello4
notfexists5=what

flist= xwsl.bat xx.csv "\program files (x86)\desktop.ini" \pagefile.sys

notflist= notme hello4 what
```

(although I've manually added some whitespace for ease of viewing)

The `for..%%b...for...%%a...` simply deletes any existing variablenames starting `fexists` or `notfexists` so that *if* they exist, they'll be removed.

then initialise `fcount` to count the arguments processed and the list strings to empty.

For each argument, count the argument in `fcount` and test whether it is an existing filename.

If it is, accumulate it into `flist`, set the variable `fexists#` to the argument string and show the two parts of the full filename - the drive/path and the name/extension.

If it is not an existing filename, then simply accumulate it into `notflist`

Then show the results...

Best way IMHO to ask such a question is to give examples of the input conditions and output data required.

Comment: Thank you for this - but I'm sorry to say I know too little about it to see exactly what the effect is. I see that if my command-line parameters are oneparam twoparm c:\filename, I end with fexists3=c:\filename. But what I don't see is how I can clear %3 if %3 contains a filename that exists.

Probably I asked the question in the wrong way, or I simply don't understand the answer. I'm sorry to come back for more help this way.

Thanks again!

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for: a thousand thanks for, and apologies for not spelling out exactly what I was looking for in the first place. I'll get this right in the future. Meanwhile, this forum is an amazing resource - after hours of banging my forehead against the table to solve two questions, the answers arrived almost instantly. Thank you agai.

Comment: @emendelosn Just a tip - look at the tour and note the green tick. http://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: Got it! I didn't realize it was as easy as clicking the green mark...  And I also added the batch file that the answer let me write, which was exactly what I hoped for.